# How to show a custom message based on the password strength

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Hi I have the following piece of code that basically checking the strength of the password and showing a div with colors based on the strength. Like a strength meter. How can I mutate the content of the div based on the strength of the password, like if the password is weak, color change to red and content says "Weak passwrd!!", if the password is moderate then content should be "Moderate password" etc. Also I would like to add a check box in the divs so if the condition is met then the color of the check box shud change to green if not then red. etc.

My codes:

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">


    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>My AngularJS App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="stageController">
        <form name="myForm" novalidate>
          <label for="pw">Type a password</label><br/>
            <input type="password" ng-model="pw" name="pw" id="pw" />
            <li id="strength" check-strength="pw"></li>
        </form>        
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
input.ng-pristine + ul#strength {
    display:none;
}
ul#strength {
    display:inline;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:2px;
}
.point:last {
    margin:0 !important;
}
.point {
    background:#DDD;
    border-radius:2px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:5px;
    margin-right:1px;
    width:20px;
}
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:5px;
}
```

AngularJS:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directives']);

/* Controllers */
function stageController($scope) {
    $scope.pw = '';
}

/* Directives */
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).

directive('checkStrength', function () {

    return {
        replace: false,
        restrict: 'EACM',
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

            var strength = {
                colors: ['#F00', '#F90', '#FF0', '#9F0', '#0F0'],
                mesureStrength: function (p) {

                    var _force = 0;                    
                    var _regex = /[$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]/g;

                    var _lowerLetters = /[a-z]+/.test(p);                    
                    var _upperLetters = /[A-Z]+/.test(p);
                    var _numbers = /[0-9]+/.test(p);
                    var _symbols = _regex.test(p);

                    var _flags = [_lowerLetters, _upperLetters, _numbers, _symbols];                    
                    var _passedMatches = $.grep(_flags, function (el) { return el === true; }).length;                                          

                    _force += 2 * p.length + ((p.length >= 10) ? 1 : 0);
                    _force += _passedMatches * 10;

                    // penality (short password)
                    _force = (p.length <= 6) ? Math.min(_force, 10) : _force;                                      

                    // penality (poor variety of characters)
                    _force = (_passedMatches == 1) ? Math.min(_force, 10) : _force;
                    _force = (_passedMatches == 2) ? Math.min(_force, 20) : _force;
                    _force = (_passedMatches == 3) ? Math.min(_force, 40) : _force;

                    return _force;

                },
                getColor: function (s) {

                    var idx = 0;
                    if (s <= 10) { idx = 0; }
                    else if (s <= 20) { idx = 1; }
                    else if (s <= 30) { idx = 2; }
                    else if (s <= 40) { idx = 3; }
                    else { idx = 4; }

                    return { idx: idx + 1, col: this.colors[idx] };

                }
            };

            scope.$watch(iAttrs.checkStrength, function () {
                if (scope.pw === '') {
                    iElement.css({ "display": "none"  });
                } else {
                    var c = strength.getColor(strength.mesureStrength(scope.pw));
                    iElement.css({ "display": "inline" });
                    iElement.children('div')
                        .css({ "background": "#DDD" })
                        .slice(0, c.idx)
                        .css({ "background": c.col });
                }
            });

        },
        template: '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.</div>'
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some code related your post, this may help you a lot

http://codepen.io/yukulele/pen/xbRpRa

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.pass="abc123456";
  $scope.v=function(){
    return test($scope.pass);
  };
});

function test(pass){
  if(pass == null)
    return -1;
  var s = 0;
  if(pass.length<6)
    return 0;
  if( /[0-9]/.test( pass ) )
    s++;
  if( /[a-z]/.test( pass ) )
    s++;
  if( /[A-Z]/.test( pass ) )
    s++;
  if( /[^A-Z-0-9]/i.test( pass ) )
    s++;
  return s;
}
```

```css
html{
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #777;
}

label{
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label>
    password:
    <input
           autofocus
           type="text"
           ng-model="pass"/>
  </label>
  <label>
    {{v()}}
    <span ng-if="v() < 2">Weak passwrd!!</span>
    <span ng-if="v() > 3">Strong password</span>
  </label>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Abhi! But its not what I am looking for but there some ideas which i can follow

Comment: Sounds good! Yes I know this is now proper answer but you can take some idea from this, after all you are a developer